# Start process on a specific screen using electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, windows-10

I'm developing a small program for my church that opens a windows file (.exe, .mp4, ...) and places it on a specific screen using Electron.

However I only have knowledge using C#, [Build monitor switcher](https://gist.github.com/reinhardholl/013a7c3fa319beeaf534#file-display-cs)

Do I need to use some kind of windows native library, for example the [FFI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-node-ffi) that calls the windows API? Is there any way I can set the target screen before the app opens using electron?

Comment: What do you mean by a "windows" file? Is it a specific window within your Electron application, a program separate from your Electron application or something else again?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I want it to open some windows application, for example (.exe, .mp4, .mp3, ...) on the other screen

Comment: @Isaac Is the question about Windows OS correct?

Comment: Ah, if it's Windows API, it's Windows OS. Okay.

Comment: Hi @lowfront, yes it is about Windows 10. I edited my question, sorry

Comment: Since you have the C# code for it, couldnt you just integrate it in your nodejs app, using something like https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/addons.html#addons_c_addons? So I guess my answer would be "yes" to "Do I need to use some kind of windows native library, for example the FFI that".

Comment: Ah ok, so this is the only way. I'll have to build an external app and make the call through electron.

Comment: @Isaac Open file -> Asynchronous loop until window handle is found -> positioning window handle found (using ffi and `SetWindowPos`). But, I was researching the data and found that finding the window handle was not a simple task due to text encoding problems. So I'm looking for a window handle yet, but if you are looking for a way to use ffi on Electron, the [link](https://gist.github.com/lowfront/7c7e5d9b041bf0b76f876767242de249) will be helpful.

Comment: Of course, as you said, it is possible to build C# and use it in a way that executes on Electron.